# How to force a really long word to stay on the same line as an image?

Tags: css, html

I'd like to force the text of a really long word to stay on the same line as my image. I know the word will need to wrap but I'd like the first line to stay aligned with the image instead of the first line jumping to the line after the image. My layout needs to be dynamic so setting a static width or height for the text is out of the question. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<img class='inline-img' src='design/dislike.png'/>
<p class='inline-text'>LotsoftextLotsoftextLotsoftextLotsoftextLotsoftextLotsoftextLotsoftextLotsoftextLotsoftextLotsoftext</p>
```

CSS:

```
img.inline-img { height: 24px; width: 24px; margin-right: 4px; float:left; }
p.inline-text { color:#F00; word-wrap:break-word; display: inline;}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JvFAw/

UPDATE: I may put the image in the background of a parent DIV and use a margin to offset the text from the image unless somebody can suggest something more elegant

UPDATE2: Made a real world example as recommended by paulie_d

http://jsfiddle.net/JvFAw/4/

Comment: I wanted to say it is not possible. but something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/JvFAw/1/

Comment: "Realworld" problem?.

Comment: @caramba The only problem with your solution is that the text will overlap the image if the image is higher than one line of text

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes, I have a div that will be filled with user data and it's possible the user will type a long word.

Comment: Yes, but is there an **actual** word that they would type in that would cause this problem..hence "RealWorld"?

Comment: How would the image and text be wrapped? Is there a limitation on that element's width? At the moment we really don't have a context...leaving aside the actually likelihood of the actual requirement.

Comment: @Paulie_D The field shrinks pretty small on mobile devices so it could be overflowed with a word like "superficially."

Comment: "The field shrinks a pretty small on mobile devices so it could be overflowed with a word like "superficially." JSFddle with actual structure need I feel.

Comment: @Paulie_D To be precise, the max width on a mobile device will be 211.5px. I'll make a new JSFddle.

Comment: You might want to look into the hyphenation css property, that with a js polyfill might do ya.

Comment: @jfelsinger From what I'm reading, the "hyphens" property control relies on words found in the dictionary. Unfortunately, I can't guarantee my users will use real english words all of the time; they may just forget to put a space between two words or make up their own (this is the internet after all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For lack of a more elegant solution, I think I'll do this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <p class='inline-text'>antidisestablishmentarianismism</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.container {
    max-width: 211.5px;
    background: url(http://www.geoengineer.org/templates/rt_voxel/images/icons/icon-home.png) no-repeat left top;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
p.inline-text {
    color:#F00;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JvFAw/7/

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo-class "first-line" and "white-space" property might be what your looking for.

```
p:first-line {
white-space: nowrap;
```

}

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3afirst-line)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space